# eVRC reader get EF.Registration length

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader

How can I get the exact length of EF.Registration? After I select the EF.Registration_A (D001) I read the FCP response with the length of EF. But the length is always the same 4096.
I would like to get the exact lenght of data which is filled in EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the sizes of the EF's are predetermined *before personalization* (so you are sure everything fits). In that case you need to establish the size of the EF from the EF itself. Can you post the first 20 bytes or so of EF.Registration?

Comment: I finally solve the problem. First I read block of data e.g. 20 bytes, the first tag always starts with value 78 (EU directive) after that I am searching for the inter-industry template which stores all the object. This template starts with tag 71 (EF.Registration_A), the next value 82 defines that the length has another 2 bytes. This 2 bytes stores the length of whole template, all the data.

Comment: Sounds like BER encoding by the way, so you could use BER decoder to find out the length (it could also be `81 NN` or just `NN` where `NN` is the size). Beware that it may not always be `82 NN NN` in other words.